# How do you implement heartbeat-like functionality using Reactor's Flux?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Let's imagine there is a `Flux` emitting some payloads:

```
Flux<Integer> payloads = Flux.range(0, 5)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
```

This one just emits integers between 0 and 4, once per 2 seconds.

The task is to mix another signal into this `Flux`. That another signal just emits something every N units of time. Something like this:

```
Flux<Integer> heartbeats = Flux.just(-1)
        .repeat()
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
```

1. The resulting `Flux` should output numbers from 0 to 4 once per 2 seconds, also number -1 each 1 second
2. Also, the resulting `Flux` must complete as soon as `payloads` `Flux` completes
3. It should propagate any error signal that any of the two `Flux`es emit

(Please note that the example described above is just for illustration purposes. The real `Flux` emitting payloads may emit at inpredictable rate: sometimes fast, sometimes slowly, sometimes not emitting at all for long periods of time).

The best I could achieve with the 'out-of-the-box' operators was

```
Flux<Integer> flux = payloads.mergeWith(heartbeats);
```

But this violates requirement 2 as the merge result only completes when all the merge components complete, and the `heartbeats` does not ever complete.

(Actually, this could be made work if there was a flag that is set to true when the `payloads` completes, and `repeat(BooleanSupplier)` variant was used instead of `repeat()` on the `heartbeats`, but this would delay the completion of the resulting `Flux` till the moment of the next heartbeat.)

The next thing to try is to write my own `Publisher` implementation that would work in the way that is required for my task, but I'd like to avoid this as implementing a `Publisher`+`Subscription` correctly seems to be a tricky task.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: For me, bonus would be that hearthbeat would emmit only when there is silence for more than  2 seconds from payloads flux. (4. requirement for me)

Answer (score 1):

*FluxSink API* might be able to help to implement your requirements. You can access the API through [Flux::create](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-) and use the `FluxSink` emitter to send the emitted signals downstream.

Here is a simple implementation in Kotlin:

```
val flux = Flux.create<Int> { emitter ->
    payloads.subscribe(
        { emitter.next(it) },
        { emitter.error(it) },
        { emitter.complete() },
    )

    heartbeats.subscribe(
        { emitter.next(it) },
        { emitter.error(it) },
    )
}
```

Please note, that this implementation turns *payloads* and *heartbeats* to hot `Flux`es in a generic case.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It really helped, but after testing I found a couple of flaws with the provided code. First of all, it does not handle cancellation: neither of the input publishers gets destroyed on cancellation of s subscription to the merged one. Also, `heartbeats` never gets cancelled on `payloads` completion. And the demand will be unlimited (`Long.MAX_VALUE`). I've tried to fix this issues in my own answer. Anyway thank you very much for the hint with `Flux.create()`!

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of @zokni, here is what I was able to achieve using `Flux.create()`:

```
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.create(sink -> {
    AtomicReference<Subscription> payloadSubscription = new AtomicReference<>();
    AtomicReference<Subscription> heartbeatsSubscription = new AtomicReference<>();

    payloads.subscribe(
            t -> {
                sink.next(t);
                payloadSubscription.get().request(1);
            },
            sink::error,
            () -> {
                sink.complete();
                heartbeatsSubscription.get().cancel();
            },
            subscription -> {
                payloadSubscription.set(subscription);
                subscription.request(1);
            }
    );
    heartbeats.subscribe(sink::next, sink::error, () -> {}, subscription -> {
        heartbeatsSubscription.set(subscription);
        subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    });

    sink.onCancel(() -> {
        payloadSubscription.get().cancel();
        heartbeatsSubscription.get().cancel();
    });
});
```

This solution is pretty verbose, but it has the following handy properties:

1. The completion of the `payloads` publisher makes the merged publisher complete as well
2. Both `payloads`'s and `heartbeats`' subscriptions are cancelled on the cancellation of the merged publisher subscription
3. `heartbeats`' subscription is cancelled properly on `payloads` completion
4. Data is requested from `payloads` one by one element, instead of an unbounded demand
5. Repetitive subscription to the merged publisher (using `Flux.repeat()`) produce the expected results

I'm still not sure whether it's ok to ask for `Long.MAX_VALUE` from `heartbeats`, maybe it makes sense to do the same there: ask another element only after the previous was consumed, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with only out-of-the-box operators:

```java
Flux<Integer> payloadsShared = payloads.publish().refCount(2);
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.merge(payloadsShared,
        heartbeats.takeUntilOther(payloadsShared.ignoreElements()));
```

I'm using [`Flux.takeUntilOther(Publisher)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeUntilOther-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) to take elements from the heartbeat Flux until the payloads Flux emits an onComplete signal. Since `takeUntilOther` completes on the first received *signal* (onComplete or onNext), I drop the onNext signals with [`Flux.ignoreElements()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#ignoreElements--).

The original payloads Flux still has to be merged to this modified heartbeat. To allow the Flux to be processed by two Flux pipelines, I use [`Flux.publish().refCount(2)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ConnectableFlux.html#refCount-int-).

Answer (score -1):

"seems to be a tricky task" - yes it is tricky unless you use the right tool for this. The solution you need is an actor with one output port and ability to delay, taken from my library [df4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.df4j/df4j-core/8.3):

```
import org.df4j.core.port.OutFlow;
import org.df4j.core.dataflow.Actor;

class DelayActor extends Actor {
    OutFlow<Integer> out = new OutFlow<>(this) ;
    int period = 1000; // ms
    int cnt = 0;
    int maxValue = 4;

    @Override
    protected void runAction() throws Throwable {
        out.onNext(-1);
        if (cnt % 2 == 0) {
            int value = cnt / 2;
            out.onNext(value);
            if (value == maxValue) {
                complete();
                out.onComplete();
                return;
            }
        }
        cnt++;
        delay(period);
    }
}
```

Port `OutFlow out` implements `org.reactivestreams.Publisher` and can accept all `org.reactivestreams.Subscriber`s. If `Flux` is needed, it can be obtained as `Flux.from(actor.out)`.

Comment: Thank you Alexei, but I was probably too specific with the toy task I described (just for the sake of illustration). In reality, I need to mix the heartbeats signal to a `Flux` that has no known relation with the emission rate. It could emit a thousand times per second, or it could do so once per minute, or never emit anything, or it could do all of the above in different times of its life. Your solution, if I understand it correctly, bakes the '-1 each 2 seconds, 0-4 once per second' logic together, and it does not seem to work for the generic case.

Answer (score -1):

So, we'd like to subscribe same subscriber to two different publishers. For some reasons, it is prohibited by the specification of reactive streams. Luckily, my asynchronous library [DF4J](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j/tree/ver8.3) implements, among others, communication protocol which I named `ReverseFlow`, where multiple producers can feed the same consumer - just like many threads can write to the same BlockingQueue, but in asynchronous fashion.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import org.df4j.core.communicator.AsyncArrayBlockingQueue;
import org.df4j.core.dataflow.Actor;
import org.df4j.core.port.InpFlow;
import org.df4j.core.port.OutChannel;
import org.junit.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

/** converts reactive stream into ReverseFlow.Producer */
class Adapter<T> extends Actor {
    public InpFlow<T> inp = new InpFlow<>(this);
    public OutChannel<T> out = new OutChannel<>(this);

    {start();}

    @Override
    protected void runAction() throws Throwable {
        if (inp.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
            out.onError(inp.getCompletionException());
        } else if (inp.isCompleted()) {
            out.onComplete();
        } else {
            out.onNext(inp.remove());
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void mergeTest() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux<Integer> payloads = Flux.range(0, 5)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    Adapter<Integer> adapter1 = new Adapter<>();
    payloads.subscribe(adapter1.inp);
    Flux<Integer> heartbeats = Flux.just(-1)
        .repeat()
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    Adapter<Integer> adapter2 = new Adapter<>();
    heartbeats.subscribe(adapter2.inp);
    /* we use a queue with asynchronous interfaces on both ends */
    AsyncArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new AsyncArrayBlockingQueue<>();
    queue.feedFrom(adapter1.out);
    queue.feedFrom(adapter2.out);
    /* on the output end, AsyncArrayBlockingQueue is an ordinary Publisher */
    Flux<Integer> merged = Flux.from(queue);
    merged.subscribe(System.out::println);
    Thread.sleep(13000);
}

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.df4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>df4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Using custom library when there are nice solutions without one, is not an answer for me.